# TopicAuthorizationException with Kafka SASL/Plain authentication

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

I have created below jaas file and exported using `KAFKA_OPTS`.

```
KafkaServer {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="1nJ8ZVpGaJ"
user_admin="1nJ8ZVpGaJ"
user_kafka="kafka123$"
user_kafdrop="kafdrop123$";

org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
username="admin"
password="admin-secret";
};
Client {
org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
username="zookeeperUser"
password="zookeeperPassword";
};
```

Here in my java code, I am using this user `kafdrop` for `SASL/Plain` mechanism. If I directly use this user getting `TopicAuthorizationException`. But If I add the same user as super user then it's working.

In case of SASL/SCRAM (SHA-512, SHA-256), we are using `kafka-acl` utilty to provide the access to the topics.

How to mange the topic level access in SASL/Plain to particular user.  Do we need make every user as super user?

Advance in Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to work as a root. But, if you run kafka in docker, you need to chown your file. You can find it in [Github](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka)

> NOTE: As this is a non-root container, the mounted files and
> directories must have the proper permissions for the UID 1001.